# Why would a large resistor in series cause a different voltage reading?

Tags: voltage-measurement

I'm watching Electroboom and don't understand why the voltage drops when he touches the [spoon](https://youtu.be/06w3-l1AzFk?t=507). He states there must be a large resistance in series. Why would the voltage not already have dropped before touching the spoon if there was a resistor? He states he's putting his body in parallel with it but I don't really understand what the circuit diagram would look like.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First he is measuring the voltage with nothing but his multimeter. Multimeters tend to have very high internal resistances. Mine has 10 MOhm. Therefor the source doesn't have to provide a significant current. He measured ~5 volt. That would be 5 V/10 000 000 Ohm = 0,0000005 ampere.

If he touches the wire a parallel path for the electricity through his body is created. His body has a much lower resistance. I assume its about 1 kOhm. That means that there should be a higher current than before but the source isn't powerful enough to provide that current. Therefor the voltage has to drop. Otherwise the circuit would violate Ohms Law which is V=R*I.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent resistance of a group of parallel resistors is always a number smaller than the smallest individual resistance in that group.

So you can see here than as long as you introduce your body as a parallel resistance to anything after a resistance in series with the source, the total resistance seen by the source will decrease causing more current to flow through the series resistance which drops the voltage more than it otherwise would at the point being measured in the middle of the divider.

If that series output impedance is very high the it does not take much additional current to cause a huge voltage drop across the resistor. The multi-meter is designed to have a high input resistance in order to minimize the additional current flow which would distort the voltage readings. But your body's impedance is much lower.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDnTP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: I added in resistances to show when the water is a continuous chain from the showerhead all the way to some ground point (maybe the faucet or pipes) and when the water stream is broken.

Comment: What is the non spoon other probe touched to? What is he measuring the voltage across?

Comment: The ground, I believe. I didn't watch the video too carefully.

Comment: but what are the two probes touching? One is the showerhead the other is the ground?

Comment: @user5389726598465 One is the showerhead and he says his faucet, which is ground @7:55.

Comment: OK, the water's resistance is being measured.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Yeah. I think the current is travelling through the water and not the showerhead case itself. That's why he said you don't want to get it in your eyes.

Comment: I almost understand. So what value resistance would the parallel water have using @hanslhansl 's numbers to make this calculation work?

Comment: @user5389726598465 I don't know the numbers. But the water might actually be part of the series output resistance, not a parallel one unless the stream of water is continuous all the way to the bottom and then makes contact with ground in the pipes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107364/discussion-between-user5389726598465-and-dknguyen).

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you have not touched the circuit. Then the voltage across R2 will be **(R2/(R3+R2))*V(input)**

This is called voltage divider law. Now if you touch the circuit, a current will flow through your body. You can assume that a new resistance has been connected against R2. So the equivalent resistance will be lower than R2. As the value of R2 is changed, so the voltage across it will also change.